# how to fix "app stopped unexpectedly" on mobile. App is running in unity but not in android phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am designing an experiment in unity. It is running on it but not on the android phone. I have tried by changing all the settings. I don't know much about coding but the program is just copied from another program where it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect your android device with android device monitor and run the app. So that you will get to know which causes the problem to crash the app.You can check the log on using this monitor. Please have some google search to get more info regarding this.
For more info follow the following link.
 https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor